# - using charAt I am trying to write a code which should display which word as unique character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, function

- i am new to js.
- using charAt I am trying to write a code which should display which word as unique character.
- i achieved using array https://jsfiddle.net/at661zsu/
- but how to achieve using charAt.
- providing code below

```or-tag-here
//var wholeWord = "pak";
var wholeWord = "pakk";

for(i=0;  i<wholeWord.length; i++) {
    var firsLoopCharacter = wholeWord.charAt(i);
    var unique = true;


    for(j=0; j<wholeWord.length; j++) {
        var secondLoopCharacter = wholeWord.charAt(j);

        if( i === j)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if( firsLoopCharacter === secondLoopCharacter[j] )  {
            unique = false;     
            break;
        }

    }
}


if (unique) {
    console.log("its an unique string");
}

else {
    console.log("not unique string");
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use String::charAt ?

Comment: @GeorgeSimms requirement is I should not use array...can you update in my code...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test if a string doesn't contain duplicate characters, here's a function that uses [**String.prototype.charAt()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt):

```
function isUniqueCharsString(str) {
  var chars = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(chars.indexOf(str.charAt(i))>=0){
        return false;
    }else{
        chars.push(str.charAt(i));
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

It loops over the string characters and store unique charcters into a temporary array and test upon it.

Here's a **Demo**:

```js
var wholeWord = "pak";

function isUniqueCharsString(str) {
  var chars = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (chars.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) >= 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      chars.push(str.charAt(i));
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(isUniqueCharsString(wholeWord));
```